# How to compute the difference between binary fields?

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I want to have a field that's stored as a `binary(64)` (fixed length) and then I want to be able to query the "closest match". To do so, I just want to find the absolute difference between each byte, and then sum the differences.

An example w/ four-byte strings:

```
  13 AF 83 52
- E9 B4 9C 19
  -----------
  D6 05 19 39

D6 + 05 + 19 + 39 = 12D = 301 base 10
```

I'm using the entity-framework, so preferably I'd write this in Linq, but if that's not possible, raw-SQL is a possibility.

I don't anticipate this being very fast, which is why I plan on narrowing down the results as much as possible first, using another key. Is this possible to do in Linq/SQL?

Otherwise, I figure I can use 64 single-byte fields, but I don't really want to code that by hand (there's no way I could write a loop, is there?).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this, on the 4-byte example:

```
DECLARE @b1 BINARY(4)=0x13+0xAF+0x83+0x52;
DECLARE @b2 BINARY(4)=0xE9+0xB4+0x9C+0x19;

SELECT ABS(CAST(SUBSTRING(@b1,1,1) AS INT)-CAST(SUBSTRING(@b2,1,1) AS INT))
+ ABS(CAST(SUBSTRING(@b1,2,1) AS INT)-CAST(SUBSTRING(@b2,2,1) AS INT))
+ ABS(CAST(SUBSTRING(@b1,3,1) AS INT)-CAST(SUBSTRING(@b2,3,1) AS INT))
+ ABS(CAST(SUBSTRING(@b1,4,1) AS INT)-CAST(SUBSTRING(@b2,4,1) AS INT))
```

Result:
301 (base 10)

Comment: Oh good... I didn't mess up my math then :D Haha...that SQL wouldn't be too hard to generate programmatically, but is there no way to do it in Linq?

Comment: Not being a Linq expert, I would say you should be able to since the SQL function calls are limited to basic ANSI.